# Generating random list

Tags: random, examdesign

I have to prepare an exam for a large number of students which includes a multiple choice quiz. We do have an e-learning system that allows to manage online quizzes (we used it during the covid emergency) but unfortunately we don't have a computer room large enough to allow all the students to take the exam at the same time.

I thought that maybe TeX can be of some help.

More precisely, I would need a TeX package that does the following.

Given n groups of questions, each group containing many of them, the routine should choose randomly exactly one question out of each group and print out a pdf where the chosen n questions are presented in a random order.

Moreover the routine needs to run N times where N is the number of students taking the exam.

Is this possible?

Comment: `automultiplechoice` does what you are looking for and has  LaTeX support https://download.auto-multiple-choice.net/auto-multiple-choice.en.pdf  See pages #14  and 16.

Comment: Should the set of questions picked at random be the same for each student, only in another order, or should the test be fully randomized for N students? Should this be in the same PDF output or do you want to have a different PDF for each student (the latter requires external tools)?

Comment: AMC allows same questions in different order (of the answer also)  as ell as random questions for every exam, but in this method the student will never be responsible for a bad score. You are the one to blame because of your unfairly selections of questions. Then you can claim that questions were chosen at random and such and such ... You're warned.